# PHP preg_match get text between specific words

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to get the text between two specific words of a string.
Here is my current code:

```
$test = "13,216 Starting at: $2.03 USD Clutch Case Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 758 Starting at: $2.55 USD Clutch Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 1,048 Starting at: $2.55 USD Spectrum 2 Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 1,028 Starting at: $2.60 USD Spectrum Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 1,421 Starting at: $7.76 USD AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 206,745 Starting at: $0.29 USD Boston 2018 Attending Legends Autograph Capsule Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 461 Starting at: $2.56 USD Glove Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 323,020 Starting at: $0.30 USD Boston 2018 Returning Challengers Autograph Capsule Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 0 Starting at: $12.01 USD AK-47 | Frontside Misty (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 615 Starting at: $2.55 USD Gamma 2 Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 636 Starting at: $2.57 USD Gamma Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 1,017 Starting at: $1.45 USD AK-47 | Elite Build (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 863 Starting at: $1.77 USD AK-47 | Elite Build (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 233 Starting at: $11.04 USD M4A4 | Desolate Space (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 183 Starting at: $39.85 USD AWP | Asiimov (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 1,237 Starting at: $2.55 USD Operation Hydra Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 1,034 Starting at: $1.50 USD AWP | Worm God (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 716 Starting at: $2.21 USD AWP | Phobos (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 102 Starting at: $38.14 USD AWP | Hyper Beast (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 435 Starting at: $10.32 USD AWP | Fever Dream (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 20 Starting at: $14.87 USD USP-S | Cortex (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 383 Starting at: $3.17 USD M4A4 | Evil Daimyo (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 45 Starting at: $28.58 USD AWP | Mortis (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 240,104 Starting at: $0.05 USD Spectrum 2 Case Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 817 Starting at: $6.00 USD M4A1-S | Decimator (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 45 Starting at: $36.38 USD AWP | Mortis (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 73 Starting at: $52.99 USD AK-47 | Bloodsport (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 982 Starting at: $1.41 USD AWP | Worm God (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 46,075 Starting at: $0.03 USD AUG | Contractor (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 728 Starting at: $1.12 USD AK-47 | Elite Build (Well-Worn) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 8,412 Starting at: $1.61 USD Operation Hydra Case Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 443 Starting at: $8.67 USD AWP | Fever Dream (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 354 Starting at: $3.10 USD USP-S | Cyrex (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 286 Starting at: $2.02 USD USP-S | Cyrex (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 253 Starting at: $30.84 USD AWP | Asiimov (Battle-Scarred) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 247 Starting at: $11.59 USD AWP | Man-o'-war (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 948 Starting at: $2.04 USD Name Tag Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 415 Starting at: $3.70 USD M4A1-S | Leaded Glass (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 135 Starting at: $19.20 USD AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 117 Starting at: $33.52 USD AWP | Asiimov (Well-Worn) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 301 Starting at: $3.53 USD AWP | Sun in Leo (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 249 Starting at: $3.69 USD Glock-18 | Water Elemental (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 241 Starting at: $7.50 USD AK-47 | Orbit Mk01 (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 28 Starting at: $54.62 USD AWP | Mortis (Factory New) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 402 Starting at: $2.49 USD M4A4 | Evil Daimyo (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 815 Starting at: $2.04 USD AWP | Worm God (Factory New) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 430 Starting at: $2.11 USD AWP | Phobos (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 1,505 Starting at: $0.99 USD AWP | Pit Viper (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 1,244 Starting at: $10.43 USD Operation Bravo Case Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 774 Starting at: $2.58 USD Operation Phoenix Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 314 Starting at: $1.95 USD AK-47 | Emerald Pinstripe (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 322 Starting at: $6.76 USD AK-47 | Orbit Mk01 (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 260 Starting at: $8.32 USD M4A1-S | Hyper Beast (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 250 Starting at: $2.23 USD AWP | Sun in Leo (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 197 Starting at: $6.56 USD M4A4 | 龍王 (Dragon King) (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 0 Starting at: $13.63 USD AWP | Redline (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 162 Starting at: $22.46 USD AK-47 | Neon Revolution (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 407 Starting at: $2.56 USD Shadow Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 901 Starting at: $2.56 USD Chroma 2 Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 9,672 Starting at: $0.80 USD Huntsman Weapon Case Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 243 Starting at: $3.99 USD StatTrak™ AK-47 | Elite Build (Well-Worn) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 107 Starting at: $3.56 USD Glock-18 | Moonrise (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 122 Starting at: $15.33 USD M4A4 | Desolate Space (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 140 Starting at: $9.61 USD M4A4 | Desolate Space (Well-Worn) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 594 Starting at: $1.33 USD AWP | Pit Viper (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 149 Starting at: $2.61 USD Operation Breakout Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 270 Starting at: $4.99 USD Glock-18 | Water Elemental (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 244 Starting at: $4.83 USD AWP | Elite Build (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 129 Starting at: $15.58 USD M4A1-S | Hyper Beast (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 0 Starting at: $3.16 USD Desert Eagle | Conspiracy (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 347 Starting at: $7.96 USD M4A1-S | Decimator (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 350 Starting at: $1.58 USD USP-S | Guardian (Factory New) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 124 Starting at: $14.73 USD AK-47 | Point Disarray (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 837 Starting at: $0.95 USD M4A1-S | Flashback (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 265 Starting at: $1.27 USD USP-S | Blueprint (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 272 Starting at: $3.82 USD M4A4 | Griffin (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 232 Starting at: $2.59 USD Operation Wildfire Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 5,354 Starting at: $0.19 USD AK-47 | Safari Mesh (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 455 Starting at: $2.58 USD Falchion Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 107 Starting at: $29.50 USD AK-47 | Vulcan (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 0 Starting at: $18.36 USD AWP | Redline (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 778 Starting at: $1.27 USD Five-SeveN | Monkey Business (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 527 Starting at: $1.24 USD AK-47 | Elite Build (Battle-Scarred) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 433 Starting at: $2.55 USD Chroma Case Key Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 393 Starting at: $4.86 USD StatTrak™ AK-47 | Elite Build (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 269 Starting at: $3.50 USD AK-47 | Cartel (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 521 Starting at: $2.83 USD AWP | Phobos (Factory New) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 54 Starting at: $27.53 USD AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 427 Starting at: $1.23 USD USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 158 Starting at: $26.04 USD AWP | BOOM (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 432 Starting at: $1.66 USD M4A1-S | Flashback (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 459 Starting at: $1.24 USD USP-S | Torque (Factory New) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 341 Starting at: $1.00 USD USP-S | Torque (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 305 Starting at: $5.03 USD Desert Eagle | Kumicho Dragon (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 268 Starting at: $8.30 USD M4A1-S | Cyrex (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 218 Starting at: $4.39 USD M4A4 | Evil Daimyo (Factory New) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 570 Starting at: $4.02 USD AK-47 | Blue Laminate (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 1,060 Starting at: $0.71 USD Desert Eagle | Oxide Blaze (Factory New) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 128 Starting at: $9.13 USD M4A4 | 龍王 (Dragon King) (Minimal Wear) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive 140 Starting at: $9.90 USD AK-47 | Orbit Mk01 (Factory New) Counter-Strike: Global Offensive";

$quantity=preg_match_all('/(USD=?) (.*?) Counter-Strike:/i',$test,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

The output looks like:

```
    [0] => USD Clutch Case 
    [1] => USD Clutch Case Key Counter-Strike:
    [2] => USD Spectrum 2 Case Key Counter-Strike:
    [3] => USD Spectrum Case Key Counter-Strike:
    [4] => USD AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested) Counter-Strike:
    [5] => USD Boston 2018 Attending Legends Autograph Capsule Counter-Strike:
```

But the output should look like this:

```
[0] => Clutch Case 
[1] => Clutch Case Key 
[2] => Spectrum 2 Case Key 
[3] => Spectrum Case Key 
[4] => AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested) 
[5] => Boston 2018 Attending Legends Autograph Capsule
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to discard the `USD=?` with `\K`, for example, and wrap the `Counter-Strike:` with a lookahead. `'/USD=?\s*\K.*?(?=\s*Counter-Strike:)/i'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew  thanks a lot. But it still Shows the  " Counter-Strike:" at the end

Comment: Well, it seems you still can use your own solution, but grab the `$matches[2]`.

Comment: This is an evidently poor dupe closure which has required Wiktor to answer the question via comment.  I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

You want to extract the substrings between `USD` and `Counter-Strike:`.  The targeted substrings in your sample data appear to not contain `:` so I will recommend a negated character class containing `:`.  Using the `\K` (fullstring restart) and a positive lookahead, you can avoid bloating your output array and simply access the fullstring match `[0]` values.  The optional equal symbol in your pattern seems completely unnecessary for your sample input, so `=?` should be removed. (Perhaps you were attempting to perform a lookbehind -- that is not the right syntax and `\K` avoids the pattern-slowing lookbehind anyhow.)

Pattern: `/USD \K[^:]*(?= Counter-Strike:)/` ([Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/i8Bgri/1))

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WOF69))

```
var_export(preg_match_all('/USD \K[^:]*(?= Counter-Strike:)/i',$test,$out)?$out[0]:[]);
```

Output: (100 matches)

```
array (
  0 => 'Clutch Case',
  1 => 'Clutch Case Key',
  2 => 'Spectrum 2 Case Key',
  3 => 'Spectrum Case Key',
  4 => 'AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)',
  5 => 'Boston 2018 Attending Legends Autograph Capsule',
  6 => 'Glove Case Key',
  7 => 'Boston 2018 Returning Challengers Autograph Capsule',
  8 => 'AK-47 | Frontside Misty (Field-Tested)',
  9 => 'Gamma 2 Case Key',
  10 => 'Gamma Case Key',
  11 => 'AK-47 | Elite Build (Field-Tested)',
  12 => 'AK-47 | Elite Build (Minimal Wear)',
  13 => 'M4A4 | Desolate Space (Field-Tested)',
  14 => 'AWP | Asiimov (Field-Tested)',
  15 => 'Operation Hydra Case Key',
  16 => 'AWP | Worm God (Minimal Wear)',
  17 => 'AWP | Phobos (Minimal Wear)',
  18 => 'AWP | Hyper Beast (Minimal Wear)',
  19 => 'AWP | Fever Dream (Minimal Wear)',
  20 => 'USP-S | Cortex (Field-Tested)',
  21 => 'M4A4 | Evil Daimyo (Minimal Wear)',
  22 => 'AWP | Mortis (Field-Tested)',
  23 => 'Spectrum 2 Case',
  24 => 'M4A1-S | Decimator (Field-Tested)',
  25 => 'AWP | Mortis (Minimal Wear)',
  26 => 'AK-47 | Bloodsport (Minimal Wear)',
  27 => 'AWP | Worm God (Field-Tested)',
  28 => 'AUG | Contractor (Field-Tested)',
  29 => 'AK-47 | Elite Build (Well-Worn)',
  30 => 'Operation Hydra Case',
  31 => 'AWP | Fever Dream (Field-Tested)',
  32 => 'USP-S | Cyrex (Minimal Wear)',
  33 => 'USP-S | Cyrex (Field-Tested)',
  34 => 'AWP | Asiimov (Battle-Scarred)',
  35 => 'AWP | Man-o\'-war (Minimal Wear)',
  36 => 'Name Tag',
  37 => 'M4A1-S | Leaded Glass (Field-Tested)',
  38 => 'AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Field-Tested)',
  39 => 'AWP | Asiimov (Well-Worn)',
  40 => 'AWP | Sun in Leo (Minimal Wear)',
  41 => 'Glock-18 | Water Elemental (Field-Tested)',
  42 => 'AK-47 | Orbit Mk01 (Minimal Wear)',
  43 => 'AWP | Mortis (Factory New)',
  44 => 'M4A4 | Evil Daimyo (Field-Tested)',
  45 => 'AWP | Worm God (Factory New)',
  46 => 'AWP | Phobos (Field-Tested)',
  47 => 'AWP | Pit Viper (Field-Tested)',
  48 => 'Operation Bravo Case',
  49 => 'Operation Phoenix Case Key',
  50 => 'AK-47 | Emerald Pinstripe (Field-Tested)',
  51 => 'AK-47 | Orbit Mk01 (Field-Tested)',
  52 => 'M4A1-S | Hyper Beast (Field-Tested)',
  53 => 'AWP | Sun in Leo (Field-Tested)',
  54 => 'M4A4 | 龍王 (Dragon King) (Field-Tested)',
  55 => 'AWP | Redline (Field-Tested)',
  56 => 'AK-47 | Neon Revolution (Field-Tested)',
  57 => 'Shadow Case Key',
  58 => 'Chroma 2 Case Key',
  59 => 'Huntsman Weapon Case',
  60 => 'StatTrak™ AK-47 | Elite Build (Well-Worn)',
  61 => 'Glock-18 | Moonrise (Field-Tested)',
  62 => 'M4A4 | Desolate Space (Minimal Wear)',
  63 => 'M4A4 | Desolate Space (Well-Worn)',
  64 => 'AWP | Pit Viper (Minimal Wear)',
  65 => 'Operation Breakout Case Key',
  66 => 'Glock-18 | Water Elemental (Minimal Wear)',
  67 => 'AWP | Elite Build (Field-Tested)',
  68 => 'M4A1-S | Hyper Beast (Minimal Wear)',
  69 => 'Desert Eagle | Conspiracy (Minimal Wear)',
  70 => 'M4A1-S | Decimator (Minimal Wear)',
  71 => 'USP-S | Guardian (Factory New)',
  72 => 'AK-47 | Point Disarray (Field-Tested)',
  73 => 'M4A1-S | Flashback (Field-Tested)',
  74 => 'USP-S | Blueprint (Field-Tested)',
  75 => 'M4A4 | Griffin (Minimal Wear)',
  76 => 'Operation Wildfire Case Key',
  77 => 'AK-47 | Safari Mesh (Field-Tested)',
  78 => 'Falchion Case Key',
  79 => 'AK-47 | Vulcan (Field-Tested)',
  80 => 'AWP | Redline (Minimal Wear)',
  81 => 'Five-SeveN | Monkey Business (Field-Tested)',
  82 => 'AK-47 | Elite Build (Battle-Scarred)',
  83 => 'Chroma Case Key',
  84 => 'StatTrak™ AK-47 | Elite Build (Field-Tested)',
  85 => 'AK-47 | Cartel (Field-Tested)',
  86 => 'AWP | Phobos (Factory New)',
  87 => 'AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Minimal Wear)',
  88 => 'USP-S | Guardian (Minimal Wear)',
  89 => 'AWP | BOOM (Minimal Wear)',
  90 => 'M4A1-S | Flashback (Minimal Wear)',
  91 => 'USP-S | Torque (Factory New)',
  92 => 'USP-S | Torque (Minimal Wear)',
  93 => 'Desert Eagle | Kumicho Dragon (Field-Tested)',
  94 => 'M4A1-S | Cyrex (Minimal Wear)',
  95 => 'M4A4 | Evil Daimyo (Factory New)',
  96 => 'AK-47 | Blue Laminate (Minimal Wear)',
  97 => 'Desert Eagle | Oxide Blaze (Factory New)',
  98 => 'M4A4 | 龍王 (Dragon King) (Minimal Wear)',
  99 => 'AK-47 | Orbit Mk01 (Factory New)',
)
```

If you find that your actual target substrings may contain `:` then you can replace the negated character class with a `.*?` but this will impact efficiency slightly because greedy patterns outperform lazy patterns.

For your sample input, the case-insensitive pattern modifier (`i`) is not necessary.  Removing it will improve pattern efficiency by 200steps and maintain the same level of accuracy.  If case-insensitivity is necessary for your real data, you should keep the `i` flag; otherwise drop it.

p.s. This pattern/call will also work:

```
var_export(preg_match_all('/USD \K([^:]*) Counter-Strike:/i',$test,$out)?$out[1]:[]);
```

with the slight side-effect of output array bloat -- `$out` will be doubled in size.